# map round border webkit

Tags: html, google-maps, css, rounded-corners

I've been trying for some hours now to get this to work..

I need to make the round border effect for the Google map.

I know there is a bug with webkit, and so far none of the solutions I have found online, nor my efforts seem to work.

Can you help me out?

---CSS---

```
#order_map_wrapper {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}

#order_map_middle {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
    overflow: hidden; 
}

#order_map { 
    height: 425px;
    width: 485px;
    -moz-border-radius: inherit;
    -webkit-border-radius: inherit;
    border-radius: inherit;
}
```

---HTML---

```
<div id="order_map_wrapper" >
    <div id="order_map_middle"> 
        <div id="order_map">
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. And your HTML markup has an error.

Comment: Indeed, Evan means the `</div` misses a `>`

Comment: that's just a typo .. even with that fixed it won't work.. but only with chrome

Answer (score 0):

I have this V2 example online:

http://maps.forum.nu/temp/gm_rounded_corners.html

I'll try to make a V3 version when I find the time.

Comment: I had seen that one already, but I need something that allows the background to show

Comment: You could do the same but with a semi-transparent image instead of an opaque one.